# In-App Purchase ios Buy All options

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Ive been looking for an answer to this, but i can't find anything. We have an application where you can buy multiple "packages" for In-App purchase as a non-consumable product. But we actually also want an option to Buy all packages as a single Unique package (perhaps at a discount). I actually don't think its possible (you can make this work ofc client side, but the user can be charged again if the users reinstalls the app and then attempts to buy a different package) but I can't find any information on it.
Hope someone can clarify this for me!

Ruud

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this should be to do a receipt refresh immediately before any attempted purchase. Then, if the user has previously bought either (a) all of your multiple packages separately, or (b) the "all packages" purchase, you can disallow the purchase from proceeding. Apple suggests regular (i.e., relatively frequently) doing a receipt refresh, so this seems in line with their guidelines.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can make another non-consumable call "Buy All", set price equal sum of all price and control all full feature in your code.

Comment: well like i said that is possible to control it from the code. But this will only work with the one instance of the app. if the user would install this on another device, or reinstall it, It would be possible that the user clicks on buying just one of the other packages instead of buying all packages. hence the user will then be charged for that single package because the itunes store doesn't have a record of the user buying that single package just the buy all package. Only way to keep track of it is with a external user database but i don't want to do that, i want itunes to handle it.

Comment: When "Buy All" is buy, check it first and disable all buttons or links to buy other packages.